# Lost Password, Problems with Downloading anything except simple thingls like word documents, prsentations and pictures

Tags: password-recovery

I lost my password for my Ubuntu account. I recently moved here from XP and have no idea what to do. I'm an youtuber and need a recording software.The account with my password was the administrator account. The other account I cannot download anything. I cannot open software manager.

Answer (score 0):

@user304781 - Can you login as yourself (not admin)?

If so, launch a terminal and `sudo su` and then `passwd`. Type the new password twice and remember the password.

Also, see [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password?rq=1).